# SQL Database Design Question: Many To One Relationship vs Full Separation

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am designing a simple database to house two types of data:

- Task (A unit of work) : Many to one relationship with users
- Post-Task Aggregate Statistic (Aggregate data about completed work) : One to one relationship with users.

The way the data flow works currently: many tasks are created in the first table and when they are completed some post task statistic is calculated and then appended (aggregated with some formulas) to the single Post-Task Aggregate Statistic row of the second table with the same user. Then the original task is deleted.

Here is an example with data values for clarity:

Task:

```
{
  id: {uuid}
  user: {user_id}
  create_time: {timestamp}
  last_modified_time: {timestamp}
  description: {string}
  completion_time: {int}
  length: {int}
  difficulty: {int}
  cost: {int}
  ...
}
```

Post-Task Aggregate Statistic

```
{
  id: {uuid}
  user: {user_id}
  total_completed_tasks: {int}
  avg_completion_time: {double}
  avg_task_length: {double}
  avg_task_difficulty: {double}
  avg_task_cost: {double}
  ...
}
```

Is there a better/smarter way to design the state for this type of data. Things I have considered:

- Not deleting the task after completion (just mark it as complete) and establish a many (task) to one (aggregate statistic) relationship
- Not aggregating the statistics and creating a one to one relationship between task and individual post task statistic and then query the statistic table and aggregate it as needed

Comment: It depends on your specific needs. If you don't care about a specific task once it's completed, then deleting it seems reasonable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - With my current feature set I do not need it, but I may need the data in the future. Would it be considered over-engineering to go for a more complex data representation now in anticipation. Or should I worry about it when/if I eventually hit that feature.

Comment: "but I may need the data in the future" *may* being the keyword here. don't do what you *may* need to in the future, do what you *will* need to in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have too much volume which could be a problem in terms of performance, I would recommend you do not materialize the aggregated statistics into a table but rather create an aggregated view on top of your `task` table. This way your aggregates are dynamically computed on the fly when you query the view and you don’t need to take care of an extra aggregation process.

Example in PostgreSQL:

```
create or replace view task_statistics as
select user
, count(distinct id) as total_completed_tasks
, avg(completion_time) as avg_completion_time
, avg(length) as avg_task_length
, avg(difficulty) as avg_difficulty
, avg(cost) as avg_cost
from task
group by user;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that certainly reduces complexity.

Comment: @ThomasChen I just formatted the answer, I could not do it before as I posted it from my mobile. It should be clearer now. Please consider marking it as an answer if you think it solves your problem. Thanks.